# Unable to deploy to sandbox - "Entity is not org-accessible"

Tags: error, sandbox, change-set, deployment

Trying to deploy from one Sandbox to another but I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Trigger Chat_GetOsForLiveAgent on LiveChatTranscript (before insert) {

    List<GettingOS__c> customSettings = GettingOS__c.getall().values();
    List<Case> lstcases = new List<Case>();
    System.debug('customSettings: ' + customSettings);


    for(LiveChatTranscript trans: Trigger.new) {
      if(trans.UserAgent!=null) {
        for(GettingOS__c cs: customSettings){
          if(trans.UserAgent.contains(cs.AbbrivOS__c)) {
            Case c = new Case(Id=trans.CaseId,OS__c=cs.Operating_System__c);
            lstcases.add(c);
          }
        }

      }
    }
    update lstcases;
}
```

Comment: Is live chat enabled in another sandbox?

Comment: @kurunve is right. I had to enable Live Agent first before deployment.

Comment: @kurunve You should post an answer to that effect (with more detail and rephrased not to be a question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some metadata components in salesforce, that are based on specific feature, like Live Agent,Sharing on specific object, Contacts to Multiple Accounts etc, and those metadata are unavailable for updates if a feature is disabled.

To ensure that all changes are properly deployed via changeset or any other deployment tool, the corresponding feature needs to be enabled in target organisation (which may be sandbox or another org).

Otherwise, next error can be shown:

> entity is not org-accessible

In these scenario, Live Chat should be enabled in target sandbox before changeset deployment.